# "sudo pip install" is showing an error code

Tags: macos, pip

I am getting an error when I try to `pip install`:

```
Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-u1pNrS-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Comment: MacOS won't let you uninstall `numpy` installed with the system python. If you need a newer version, install one as user: `pip install numpy --user`.

Comment: I know it isn't obvious from any of the documentation but you should not install packages in the system-wide Python directory. My suggestion: **carefully** delete the existing version by the commands: `cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/` then `sudo rm -rf numpy*` (-> Be careful with the rm command. No space between `numpy` and the `*`, you can type `sudo ls numpy*` before, go up in terminal history (up arrow) and replace `ls` by `rm -rf` after checking the output of ls to be only the numpy directory/file).

Comment: Then install with `python -m pip --user numpy` to avoid gambling with your system-wide Python directory.